# Workplace scheduling spreadsheet help, find (partial) duplicate in range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I work at the front desk of a tutoring and test prep center whose master schedule is a simple Google Sheets file with the schedule for each of our M-Th and Sat. sessions sharing the same spreadsheet. One problem we keep having is that sometimes, because of human error, a student's name will be placed in two different teacher's rows for the same time in the day. Below is an example of what a section of our schedule for a Thursday typically looks like:

| THURSDAY |
| --- |

| 204 | Teacher Jake | 11:00AM - 1:00PM | 1:00PM - 3:00PM | . . . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 205 |  | Alice Allison 12. SAT Math |  |  |
| 206 |  | Ben Benson 11. ACT Sci |  |  |
| 207 |  | Carl Carlson 9. SAT Math |  |  |
| 208 |  | . . . |  |  |

| 222 | Teacher Kate | 11:00AM - 1:00PM | 1:00PM - 3:00PM | . . . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 224 |  | Dan Danson 11. SAT Math |  |  |
| 223 |  | Alice Allison 12. SAT Writing |  |  |
| 225 |  | Eric Erikson 9. Calculus |  |  |
| 226 |  | . . . |  |  |

What I'm looking for is a way to be able to run a conditional formatting formula or some kind of script in Google Sheets to check if a range contains two cells that contain the same student's name. For instance, I would want to rule/condition to be automatically applied within the range B204:B226 in the above examples so that cells B205 and B223 get flagged or highlighted as containing the same student. Now, because their name is not the *only* value in those cells, I suppose that technically this formula or script would have to parse cells for what they *start* with.

I understand that I am asking for help with an extremely specific case with very, very fine parameters, but I truly don't know where else to turn. The main hurdles in my eyes are the ability to check *ranges* instead of entire columns (every weekday's schedule shares the same columns on the workbook), the ability to check for *partial* matches (we still need to be able to fill a student's cell with information besides simply their first and last name), and the ability to have this solution be automatic and dynamic such that we don't need to input anything specific for it to work for that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `B204:B226`:

```
=countif(B$204:B$226, regexextract(B204, "([A-z ]+?) \d") & "*") > 1
```

See [countif()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093480) and [regexextract()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098244).